# Maintain unitary time evolution for a nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, unitary-matrices

I want to solve a nonlinear ODE of matrix $A(t)$
$$\mathrm{i}\dot A = A(t)M(t),\:\mathrm{with}\: M(t)=A^\dagger(t)H(t)A(t)$$ where $H(t)$ and hence $M(t)$ are Hermitian. Therefore, I presume the time evolution of $A(t)$ is unitary. Is there any algorithm that can maintain this unitarity? I've heard of Crank-Nicolson, but is it for linear ODE and $M$ is independent of $t$?

Comment: Do I read that correctly that in effect the system has degree 3 in $A$ on the right side? I would have written that at $i\dot A(t)=A(t)M(t,A(t))$ with $M(t,X)=X^\dagger H(t) X$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would like to get a formula $$A_{k+1}=A_kU_k,~~~U_k=(I-\tfrac12iS_k\Delta t)(I+\tfrac12iS_kΔt)^{-1},$$ where $S_k$ is symmetric/hermitean and close to $M(t_k,A_k)$. This construction ensures that $U^*=U^{-1}$ is unitary, so that if $A_0$ has this property, it is kept over the whole integration.

Now let's compare expansions to establish second order. Just setting $S_k=M_k$ would give a first order method. For the second derivative of the exact solution we get
$$
-\ddot A=i\dot A M+iA(\dot A^*HA+A^*\dot HA+A^*H\dot A)
=AM^2+A(-M^2+iA^*\dot HA+M^2)
$$
So on the one hand
$$
A(t_k+Δt)=A_k\Bigl(I-iMΔt-\tfrac12M^2Δt^2-i\tfrac12A^*\dot HAΔt^2+O(Δt^3)\Bigr)
$$
and on the other
$$\begin{align}
A_{k+1}&=A_k\Bigl(I-\tfrac12iSΔt)(I-\tfrac12iSΔt+(\tfrac12iSΔt)^2+O(Δt^3)\Bigr)
\\
&=A_k\Bigl(I-iSΔt-\tfrac12S^2Δt^2+O(Δt^3)\Bigr)
\end{align}$$
Now try an expansion $S=M+NΔt+O(Δt^2)$. Comparing one reads off $N=\frac12A^*\dot HA$.

From this information one can construct a semi-implicit method
$$\begin{align}
S&=A_k^*H(t_k+\tfrac12Δt)A_k\\
A_{k+1}&=A_k(I-iSΔt/2)(I+iSΔt/2)^{-1}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer! I think in the first paragraph $S$ is hermitean and $U$ is unitary.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Corrected.

Comment: Could you tell us how you conceived $U_k$ in the first equation? Any reason or motivation to cast this unitary matrix in that form? Thanks.

Comment: This is a well-known trick for exponential functions using the Padé approximation or similar. You get the symmetry of the exponential correct if you compute it as $g(x/2)/g(-x/2)$. This becomes simple if $g$ itself is an approximation of the exponential, but one can cancel this by functions in $x^2$, so there is no uniqueness. Then compare to using the fraction $\frac{1+it}{1-it}$ to get a point on the unit circle, see also the Mobius transforms.